# Is it possible to detect when building in the VS IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I've added an additional after build step so that I can integrate mspec with teamcity. However I do not want to run this when I'm building in the IDE as it lengthens the time to build. Is there someway I can detect whether I'm building from the IDE and not execute this specific target? This is what I have so far.

```
<Target Name="RunSpecs">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AdditionalSettings>--teamcity</AdditionalSettings>
        <MSpecCommand>..\Lib\mspec\mspec.exe $(AdditionalSettings) "$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).dll"</MSpecCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running Specs with this command: $(MSpecCommand)" />
    <Exec Command="$(MSpecCommand)" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="RunSpecs" />
```

The easy solution is to add another build configuration but I'd prefer not to do that.

Also the TeamCity output being dumped to the output window is sort of annoying. :)

Comment: temporarily I'm only running this in the release version of the build, but still interested in knowing whether it's possible to detect whether the build is being done in the IDE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can check the property `BuildingInsideVisualStudio`.

So in your case you could do something like the following:

```
<Target Name="RunSpecs" Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'!='true' ">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AdditionalSettings>--teamcity</AdditionalSettings>
        <MSpecCommand>..\Lib\mspec\mspec.exe $(AdditionalSettings) "$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).dll"</MSpecCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running Specs with this command: $(MSpecCommand)" />
    <Exec Command="$(MSpecCommand)" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
</Target>
```

Notice the condition on the target. FYI, generally I generally [advise against putting condition on targets](http://sedodream.com/2008/06/27/MSBuildConditionsOnTargets.aspx) but this is a good usage for them.

Comment: [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2017#build-solutions)