# Msbuild question

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I have several long running custom build tasks. It looks Visual Studio, however, runs msbuild tasks on the UI thread, which was causing the IDE to hang.

I did a little bit of searching on google, and the best I could find were some bugs reports with the response "oh yeah, that's a problem, we'll maybe fix it later".

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/670873/visual-studio-ui-freezes-during-long-msbuild-task

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/3289eb7d-7989-4350-8c43-02bf9913edbd/.

So, I decided to fix it for my custom tasks by:

1. Detecting when they are running inside of Visual Studio.
2. Running the tasks on a background thread if they are
3. Adding a "MsgWaitForMultipleHandles / Custom message pump" to the UI thread to keep the UI responsive while things run.

This seems to work. I can now run my builds without the IDE freezing.

In any case, this brought up a few questions:

1. Is this safe to do? Visual studio is a massive thing. Will I run into any re-entrancy problems if I do this? Will those re-entrancy problems cause the world to end, or can I get away with ignoring them.
2. I detect Visual Studio using the technique outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313496/is-it-possible-to-detect-when-building-in-the-vs-ide). Basically, I assign the value of the "BuildingInsideVisualStudio" property to a property on the task, which I check in my Execute() method. If it's true, then I use the multi-threaded behaviour, otherwise I just use sequential behaviour. This, however, requires each target using the task to put extra goo into the msbuild file to avoid suckyness. Ideally I would like "not sucking" to be the normal behaviour, without special configuration. Is there any way I can detect visual studio inside my task's Execute() method? Can I read the project property in the task implementation without requiring custom edits to the XML? Can I interrogate the Host object somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: I read the question for "the end of the universe" part, disapointed

Comment: Wow. You make your devs go through a long running build cycle?

Comment: I'm guessing that's sarcasm? In any case.... "long running" means something different when the IDE is blocked and won't paint than it does when it's responsive.The definition of long can change significantly. Our complete build takes about 5 minutes, which isn't that slow. The complete build at my last job took about half a day. I've also worked on projects where several build labs were required to build the product within a day. So, no, we don't subject our devs to long builds. But I want the people working on my project to have productive use of their tools. Not responding == not productive.

Comment: @ScottWisniewski Hello, your workaround to keep MSBuild responsive would be very valueable to me. However, I don't have the background knowledge needed to really understand what you mean by "Adding a "MsgWaitForMultipleHandles / Custom message pump" to the UI thread". Could you please post some code (either here, or in a self-answered question about how to keep VS responsive during long builds) ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the environment variable MSBuildNoInProcNode to 1 and then launch the IDE.  This will force IDE build requests to child nodes.  Make note that this is not a fully tested scenario so there may be some unexpected behavior, but it may be an alternative for getting the result you want without having to alter your project files or all of your custom tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. All of my custom tasks have a common base class, so I only had to make the change to the tasks in one place.

Ideally I would like to avoid launching visual studio differently then normal (that's even easier to forget to do than adding goo to the xml).